# Why assign variable to itself

Tags: c

A co-worker wrote a function like this (the comment was written by me):

```
static void foo(void *arg)
{
    //arg is NOT global variable
    arg = arg;
    // call other function, but doesn't use arg
    foo2();
}
```

Is there some reason to write code like this? Does it have some special purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be for future extension purposes. Right now that argument is not used, but may be in later versions it can be used for more functionality, without changing the function signature.

Adding the purpose pointed out by *Paul R.*, `arg = arg;` statement just tries to use the `arg` to suppress compiler warnings, in order to get clean warning-free builds.

P.S.: Codes like this are also used in my company.

Comment: `static void foo(void */*arg*/)`

Comment: @EdS.: Usually these functions are present in library code of some component of a product, so you cannot change the code itself. What I mean to say is I regard the question as "why this method is used" not as "how else to use it", that's how my answer is.

Comment: I was just offering another alternative, that's all

Answer (score 9):

This is just one way of suppressing a compiler warning for an unused argument.

Other common methods are:

```
(void)arg;
```

or

```
#pragma unused (arg)    // not supported by all compilers
```

Comment: also you can start the function as `static void foo(void */*arg*/)`

Comment: The commenting-out is not valid C, you can only omit names in prototypes, not in actual function definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's done just to avoid "unused argument" warning. They could just use `__attribute__((unused))` for arg.

Comment: Isn't it specific to `gcc` ?

Comment: It is indeed. I believe other compilers have something similar to avoid the warning.